# How to Rotate and translate a figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can turn a square, around its Center, to an angle of 90 degrees.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
  \draw[thick] (0,4)--(1,2.6)--(4,0);
  \draw[thick](0,0)--(1,2.6);
  \node at (0,-0.3) {A};
  \node at (4,-0.3) {B};
  \node at (4,4.3) {C};
  \node at (0,4.3) {D};
  \node at (1.5,2.6) {P};
  \node at (0,0) {$\bullet$};
  \node at (0,4) {$\bullet$};
  \node at (4,0) {$\bullet$};
  \node at (1,2.6) {$\bullet$};
  \node at (4,4) {$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around={90:(2,2)}]
  \draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
  \draw[thick] (0,4)--(1,2.6)--(4,0);
  \draw[thick](0,0)--(1,2.6);
  \node at (-0.3,0) {A};
  \node at (4.3,0) {B};
  \node at (4.3,4) {C};
  \node at (-0.3,4) {D};
  \node at (1.5,2.6) {Q};
  \node at (0,0) {$\bullet$};
  \node at (0,4) {$\bullet$};
  \node at (4,0) {$\bullet$};
  \node at (1,2.6) {$\bullet$};
  \node at (4,4) {$\bullet$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But, the result you want to put side by side with the original figure, as in the figure. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: It is better to create the right one and rotates it around `A`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using a `pic`, as well as tikz's mechanism for labeling the nodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{point/.style={circle,fill,minimum width=1.5mm,inner sep=0mm},
         myrectangle/.pic=
          {\node[point] (A) at (0,0) {};
           \node[point] (B) at (4,0) {};
           \node[point] (C) at (4,4) {};
           \node[point] (D) at (0,4) {};
           \node[point] (P) at (1,2.6) {};
           \draw[thick]
             (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (A) -- (P)
             (B) -- (P) -- (D);
          }
         }
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic (R1) {myrectangle};
  \pic[rotate around={90:(0,0)}] (R2) {myrectangle};
  \draw[dotted] (R1P) -- (R2P);
  \node[label=below:{$A'=A$}] at (R1A) {};
  \node[label=below:$B$] at (R1B) {};
  \node[label=above:$C$] at (R1C) {};
  \node[label=above:{$B'=D$}] at (R1D) {};
  \node[label=right:$P$] at (R1P) {};
  \node[label=above:$C'$] at (R2C) {};
  \node[label=below:$D'$] at (R2D) {};
  \node[label=above:$P'$] at (R2P) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to achieve the second image, just move the second **`tikzpicture`** to to the first, and put it inside a `scope`, giving the scope the rotating option plus a shifting option to make it side by side with the other:

Also improved the drawing code as it was extremely repetitive and using Ti*k*Z Labels as well as sytles can make the code much cleaner.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={insert path={node[minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt,fill,circle, label={#1}]{}}}]
  \draw[thick] (0,0) [bullet=below:A] -- (0,4) [bullet=above:D] -- (4,4) [bullet=above:C] -- (4,0) [bullet=below:B] -- cycle;
  \draw[thick] (0,4) -- (1,2.6) [bullet=above right:P] -- (4,0) (0,0) -- (1,2.6) coordinate (P);

  \begin{scope}[rotate around={90:(2,2)}, yshift=4cm]
    \draw[thick] (0,0) [bullet=below:A] -- (0,4) [bullet=below:D] -- (4,4) [bullet=above:C] -- (4,0) [bullet=above:B] -- cycle;
  \draw[thick] (0,4) -- (1,2.6) [bullet=above left:Q] -- (4,0) (0,0) -- (1,2.6) coordinate (Q);
  \end{scope}

  \draw[dotted] (P) -- (Q);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Guilherme - Show. There remains one question, how to draw a dotted line connecting the point Q to point P?

Comment: Well, that's very simple. just name both nodes (e.g. `\node[opts] (node-name) at (x,y) {}`) and `\draw[dotted] (P) -- (Q);`

Comment: That's true. But the canvas is manipulated by pgf and *then* the coordinate is computed, so that the specified coordinates *always* points to where it actually is in the drawing. I added to the edited answer the dotted line as well as improved the drawing code, it was far too long. Hope you like and learn more from it, Ti*k*Z is fun! `:D`

Comment: Guilherme - Show!